# KONG updating plugins

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

im trying to work out how i can enable or disable a plugin using CURL... i found the following in the docs... so i can create a plugin using CURL... but i cant update the values, how do i update an existing plugin

```
https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-termination/


curl -X POST http://{HOST}:8001/plugins/ \

    --data "name=request-termination"  \

    --data "config.status_code=403" \

    --data "config.message=So long and thanks for all the fish!"


https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/admin-api/


/services/{service name or id}/plugins/{plugin id}
```

When i try patching i get {"message":"not found"}, this only happen when i use the /services/{service name or id}/plugins/{plugin id}

if i go via plugins/plugin_id it works fine...

But ideally id like to go via the service endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your service and route ?
e.g.

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X 'POST' http://localhost:8001/services -d '{"name":"peke.test.v1","url":"http://peke.was.here"}'
curl -o /dev/null -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X 'POST' http://localhost:8001/services/peke.test.v1/routes -d '{"paths":["/peke/oidc/v1"]}'
```

after that you can add a plugin to it : e.g. **acl**

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X 'POST' http://localhost:8001/services/peke.oidc.v1/plugins -d '{"name":"acl","enabled":true,"config":{"allow":["peke.oidc.v1"]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me using --form instead of --data worked.